# Uninstalled Ruby 2.4.1 and keep getting the error: "Your Ruby version is 2.4.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.3"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rvm

I tried switching to version 2.3.3 with the command `rvm use 2.3.3` and `ruby -v` shows:

`ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-linux]`

but when I run `rake db:create:all db:migrate db:seed` I keep getting the error above mentioned:

`Your Ruby version is 2.4.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.3`

I've also tried other possible fixes but none seems to work.

So I decided to uninstalled version 2.4.1 and 2.4.0 but the error keeps showing up.

What can I do?

Hope you can help and thanks!

EDIT:

The command `rvm list` shows:

`rvm rubies`

```
      jruby-9.1.7.0 [ x86_64 ]
      ruby-2.3.3 [ x86_64 ]
```

When the command `bunde -v` is run shows this:

`/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems.rb:270:in` `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems.rb:298:in activate_bin_path
    from /usr/local/bin/bundler:22:in '<main>'`

So I checked `/usr/local/lib/ruby` and there is a directory for 2.4.0 which is presumably uninstalled. Hope this helps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show your gem file and run this rvm list on your terminal

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari rvm list shows this: `rvm rubies

   jruby-9.1.7.0 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-2.3.3 [ x86_64 ]
`

Comment: does your gemfile has `ruby "2.3.3"`, if yes, create a file named `.ruby-version` and put this `ruby-2.3.3` on first line and save. restart terminal and run `bundle`.

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari The gem file is the one in my project directory? Thanks.

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon that file exists already so I changed `2.3.3` to `ruby-2.3.3` but when I run `bundle` terminal prompts: `Could not locate Gemfile`. Thanks

Comment: ummm, are you in your app directory?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon Sorry, no I wasn't but I run it again and showed this: `/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems.rb:270:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems.rb:298:in `activate_bin_path'
 from /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'`

Comment: ok, now again check ur rvm list, ruby -v and bundler -v

Comment: `rvm list:`    `jruby-9.1.7.0 [ x86_64 ]  => ruby-2.3.3 [ x86_64 ]`, ruby version is `ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859)` and `bundle -v` shows this: /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems.rb:270:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
 from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems.rb:298:in `activate_bin_path'
 from /usr/local/bin/bundler:22:in `<main>'

Comment: exactly, install bundler `gem install bundler` better if you install version which is in your lock file.

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon Thank you very much!! That solved the problem ;)

Comment: @boltzmanncte cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`can't find gem bundler` Suggests that you don't have a bundler installed, even though you have a gemfile?

Try running `gem install bundler` and that should solve the issue.